# Mastermind C++ on GoW

Tags: c++

I had a look at [that article on Guru Of the Week](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/041.htm) where a "pure" C++ solution is proposed to compute the number of exact and misplaced peg in a mastermind game, comparing a guess and the hidden code.

but when I use the code

```
string colors("BGR"), comb(4, '.'), l(comb), guess;
typedef map<int,int> M;

struct Color
{
    Color( M& cm, M& gm, int& color )
        : cm_(cm), gm_(gm), color_(color=0) { }

    void operator()( char c )
    {
        color_ += min( cm_[c], gm_[c] );
    }
    M &cm_, &gm_;
    int& color_;
};

struct Count
{
    Count( int& color, int& exact )
        : color_(color), exact_(exact=0) { }

    char operator() ( char c, char g )
    {
        return ++cm_[c], ++gm_[toupper(g)], exact_ += c == toupper(g), '.';
    }

    ~Count()
    {
        for_each( colors.begin(), colors.end(), Color( cm_, gm_, color_ ) );
    }

    M cm_, gm_;
    int &color_, &exact_;
};

char ChoosePeg()
{
    return colors[rand() % colors.size()];
}

int main()
{
    int color, exact = 0;
    srand( time(0) ), generate( comb.begin(), comb.end(), ChoosePeg );

    while( exact < comb.length() )
    {
        cout << "\n\nguess--> ", cin >> guess;
        transform( comb.begin(), comb.end(),
               guess.begin(), l.begin(),
               Count( color, exact ) );
         cout << color << ' ' << exact;
     }
     cout << " - solved!\n";
 }
```

The "color" number is always 0, even if it should be different as in the example they provide. I hard coded the code combination "RRBB" and when I enter "rbrr" the expected result is: 3 1, But I my output is:

```
guess--> rbrr
0 1
```

All idea will be welcome ?

Comment: I've not tried to figure out what is not working, but this is a horrible example of how to abuse the standard library, in order to obfuscate.  Don't program like this.  (This looks like something that was developed as a fun challenge, rather than serious code.  The parentheses at the end of the second paragraph suggest as much.)

Answer (score 0):

The number of misplaced peg (call `color` in the code) was still 0 because in the following ctor:

```
Color( M& cm, M& gm, int& color )
        : cm_(cm), gm_(gm), color_(color=0) { }
```

the author reset the `int&`value before the member initialization.
To fix that we can follow several way but the most easy is to reset the `color` value in the `Count`ctor as for the `exact`value. So `Color` and `Count`constructor become:

```
Color( M& cm, M& gm, int& color )
        : cm_(cm), gm_(gm), color_(color) { }
```

and

```
Count( int& color, int& exact )
        : color_(color = 0), exact_(exact=0) { }
```